# Setting bundle version based on git in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, plist

I am trying to set the bundle version in xcode based on git.

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=${1:-'master'}
BUILD_NUMBER=$(expr $(git rev-list $BRANCH --count) - $(git rev-list HEAD..$BRANCH --count))
echo "Updating build number to $BUILD_NUMBER using branch '$BRANCH'."

APP_INFO_PLIST="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
DSYM_INFO_PLIST="${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Info.plist"

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $BUILD_NUMBER" "$APP_INFO_PLIST"
if [ -f "$DSYM_INFO_PLIST" ] ; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $BUILD_NUMBER" "$DSYM_INFO_PLIST"
fi
```

But I run into an error on this line:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $BUILD_NUMBER" "$DSYM_INFO_PLIST"
```

I get an error reading that file "Error Reading File: ...".

However, when I check for that file it does exist.  Was it created after this build step maybe?

I did double check that this script is set to run after the Copy Bundle resources and after some of my cocoa pods stuff.

**EDIT**:
Searching around it looks like this solution was fine with xocxcodee 6.  I am running xcode 7.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was how I set the build version in xcode.  I had it set to

```
<set in build phase>
```

The plist file is xml and xcode does not escape the text you put in the build.  the '<' and '>' were screwing up the plist as it was invalid xml, which in turn threw the error when trying to read the file.

Careful the text you put in xcode for your tmp build version.